# How to implement internationalisation with AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internationalization, amazon-dynamodb

What solutions you guys are using when implementing i18n on DynamoDB? Coming for RDBMS world, I would have a separate table (lang, key, text) and then would store keys in content tables. However, in document based databases like MongoDB, you can   store localised texts [embedded in the same document](https://www.drzon.net/approaches-to-json-internationalisation-i18n/) and this gives some easier querying. However, I was unable to find anything concrete for DynamoDB. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB supports JSON documents, so you could use exactly the same structures [listed here](https://www.drzon.net/approaches-to-json-internationalisation-i18n/). For example, you could store items like this as is in DynamoDB:

```
{
  "venue_id": "C001",
  "venue_location": {
    "en": "Baker St.",
    "he": "רחוב האופה"
  }
  "venue_name": {
    "en": "Aroma Coffee",
    "he": "קפה ארומה"
  }
}
```